# Android Emulator Issues

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator, unity-game-engine

I Needed to launch Android Application in Android Emulator Using Eclipse.App installed but not opened.I Get one surprised Error At that time of opening the app i.e.,   **"Unfortunately 'Application Name' has stopped"**.So I didn't get any idea about how to solve this error.and I got the below Errors find in Debugging mode so how to solve this error Please help me.

LogCat Errors:

```
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): Process: com.***.****, PID: 1094
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.***.****/com.***.****.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub$Proxy.mkdirs(IMountService.java:750)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2160)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getObbDirs(ContextImpl.java:874)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getObbDir(ContextImpl.java:863)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getObbDir(ContextWrapper.java:220)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:177)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.***.****.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java:22)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
12-16 01:44:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     ... 11 more
```

Android Manifest File :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  package="com.***.****" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
   <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.***.****.UnityPlayerProxyActivity">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.***.****.UnityPlayerActivity">
 </activity>
 <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.***.****.UnityPlayerNativeActivity">
   <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
 </activity>
</application>
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  </manifest>
```

UnityPlayerActivity.java

```
   package com.***.****;

   import com.unity3d.player.*;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.res.Configuration;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.KeyEvent;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.Window;
   import android.view.WindowManager;

 public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity
  {
  private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

// UnityPlayer.init() should be called before attaching the view to a layout - it will load the native code.
// UnityPlayer.quit() should be the last thing called - it will unload the native code.
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
    if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
        getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

    View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
    setContentView(playerView);
    playerView.requestFocus();
}
protected void onDestroy ()
{
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
    super.onDestroy();
}

// onPause()/onResume() must be sent to UnityPlayer to enable pause and resource recreation on resume.
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
}
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}

// Pass any keys not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event)
{
    return mUnityPlayer.onKeyMultiple(keyCode, count, event);
}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return mUnityPlayer.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return mUnityPlayer.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java

```
 package com.***.****;

import com.unity3d.player.*;
import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class UnityPlayerNativeActivity extends NativeActivity
{
    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;     // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

    // UnityPlayer.init() should be called before attaching the view to a layout - it will load the native code.
    // UnityPlayer.quit() should be the last thing called - it will unload the native code.
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().takeSurface(null);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
            getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        setContentView(playerView);
        playerView.requestFocus();
    }
    protected void onDestroy ()
    {
        mUnityPlayer.quit();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // onPause()/onResume() must be sent to UnityPlayer to enable pause and resource recreation on resume.
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mUnityPlayer.pause();
    }
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
            return mUnityPlayer.onKeyMultiple(event.getKeyCode(), event.getRepeatCount(), event);
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
    }
```

UnityPlayerProxyActivity.java

```
package com.***.****;

import com.unity3d.player.*;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UnityPlayerProxyActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // If the (Native)Activity is overridden these class names must match the new activities.
        String classNames[] = { "com.***.****.UnityPlayerActivity", "com.***.****.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" };

        // Convert old PlayerPrefs (pre Unity 3.4) to new PlayerPrefs
        copyPlayerPrefs(this, classNames);

        // Start the most 'advanced' Activity supported by the current Android OS.
        // (Android OS 2.3 ('Gingerbread') and above supports NativeActivity)
        try
        {
            boolean supportsNative = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9 /*Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD*/;
            Class<?> activity = Class.forName(classNames[supportsNative ? 1 : 0]);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null)
                intent.putExtras(extras);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            finish();
        }
    }

    static protected void copyPlayerPrefs(Context context, String[] activityClassNames)
    {
        // UnityPlayer uses PackageName (bundle identifier) as PlayerPrefs identifier, starting from Unity 3.4.
        SharedPreferences packagePrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // If PlayerPrefs<package_name> already exists there is no need to
        // copy the old values; they might in fact be stale data.
        if (!packagePrefs.getAll().isEmpty())
            return;

        // Loop through the Activities and copy the contents (if any) of associated PlayerPrefs (Unity 3.3 and earlier).
        SharedPreferences.Editor playerPrefs = packagePrefs.edit();
        for (String name : activityClassNames)
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            java.util.Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();
            if (keys.isEmpty())
                continue;
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet())
            {
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                if (value.getClass() == Integer.class)
                    playerPrefs.putInt(entry.getKey(), (Integer)value);
                else if (value.getClass() == Float.class)
                    playerPrefs.putFloat(entry.getKey(), (Float)value);
                else if (value.getClass() == String.class)
                    playerPrefs.putString(entry.getKey(), (String)value);
            }
            playerPrefs.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: ur code contains error in onCreat itself.

Comment: I Posted Entire Code.So Please help me how to solve this problems And How to solve OnCreate it self Errors. @Monica

Answer (score 0):

The requestWindoFeature line should be after super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState) in your UnitPayerNativeActivity class

Comment: I has changed to as u told  but i got same errors as i posted above errors.@Vaibhav Agarwal.

Comment: Please clean your code and build it again and remove dependency of libs after that add it again and restart your system and emulator.Run your project and see error log. Right click on pro go to properties -> java build path -> libraries remove all except main android4.2 or whatever you android lib is . remove all. Clean project build again. Restart everything and run

Comment: Even Though same problem not changed .@Vaibhav Agarwal.

Comment: I got both errors one is Error Log errors & Another one is LogCat errors   on Finding debugging mode in of Eclipse.@Vaibhav Agarwal.

Comment: Ok, According to me that error log error is nothing to do with your code. You should restart you system and clean project for this and for logcat error please check line no 177 of your native activity or paste it here.

Comment: I didn't Understand what you told.This is 1 St time Using Eclipse to launch Android App.So Line no 177 of Native Activity code means I didn't understand this, Can you please explain where it is?.@Vaibhav Agarwal.

Comment: in your UnitPayerNativeActivity what you have written on line no 177 ? Is there any another class named native activity?

Comment: In UnityPlayerNativeActivity Contains 75 lines only.@Vaibhav Agarwal

Comment: and i have posted UnityPlayerNativeActivity code also please see the above codes.@Vaibhav Agarwal

Comment: Please remove that previous log cat and after changing you requestwindofeature line in native activity again post updated logcat. Plz edit your question

Comment: I Changed to LogCat errors of After Changing to requestWindoFeature line after super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState)  then  genearated LogCat errors.@Vaibhav Agarwal.

Answer (score 0):

In a general way
we use" adb install location"to install a apk to emulator.

Comment: I was tried this way also but the problem was same.that is "Unfortunately 'Application Name' has stopped".@MengMeng